# Python: Pass two strings as keyword arguments to a function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am looking to: Write a python program that demonstrates the passing of two strings as keyword arguments to a function.

I have written what I think is the correct code. Would like to know if it is correct, or what to correct.

Thank you in advance!

```
def class_students(fname,lname):
print(fname + " " + lname)

class_students("Sam" , "Walker")
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass as keyword arguments, change your code to such:

```
class_students(fname="Sam" , lname="Walker")
```

Declaring the names is useful as it assures the arguments are declared as you wish them to be. Also, order does not matter:

```
class_students(lname="Walker", fname="Sam")
```

This also works.